# Using playbin2 on android, only few audio frames can be displayed others are dropped in GstRingBuffer

Tags: android, gstreamer

I am porting `Gstreamer` to `Android`. It works fine to play audio.

But when playing video only few audio frame can be displayed at start, the others are dropped in `GstRingBuffer::default_commit` function.

In `default_commit` function, `writeseg` is less than `segdone` and `GstAudioSink` send `0x00000000 to GstAudioFlingerSink`.

My doubt is the reader thread get one segment once time, but the writer thread compose one segment need several invokes.

Could you kindly give me some suggestion or information on this issues.

Answer (score 0):

What videosink are you using? Are you using playbin2 with it? Could you modify the videosink to return from the render() vmethod immediately (not actually displaying anything) to exclude that the video rendering is starving the audio thread.